# JS make function available after object has been instantiated

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm building a JS framework using [facade pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#facadepatternjavascript) and I'm having a scoping issue.  In the html side when I execute multiple methods.  The second method fails because the first hasn't completed.  I've tried jquery deferred to no luck, and I'm thinking I may have to modify the pattern of the JS to accomplish this, **but is it possible to make a function available after an object has been instantiated?**

My guess is changing the pattern to module, but I'm unsure and before going down the millionth rabbit hole it seems wise to ask....
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
   foo.doFirst('#id');
   foo.availableSecond('#hooray');
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

**foo.doFirst();** This calls a series of functions all nested within the 'foo'.  Most importantly objects are created inside.  Specifically foo.Layers; which is an array of objects

**foo.doSecond();** This needs the array of objects created in *foo.doFirst();* to parse through and execute another function.

To note.  If I execute the first method alone, the application loads, after page load I can call the second method and it executes cleanly. Which is what makes me think I need to force the second method to wait until the first is finished.

**Second Edit: **
Below is my deferred attempt.  **goal: 'jen.infLayers' to be defined before executing**

**Third Edit**: 
foo.doFirst() = jen.doFirst();  The jen object is instantiated and jen.infLayers is instantiated as an array, after instantiation objects are pushed into it.  All this needs to occur before the function below which is what is called by jen.doSecond(), which will loop and a new object for the app to load if the titles match.

```
function addLayer(opt) {
$.when(jen.infLayers).done(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < jen.infLayers.length; i++) {
    if (jen.infLayers[i].title === opt) {
      setLayer({
        url: jen.infLayers[i].url,
        title: jen.infLayers[i].title,
        visible: jen.infLayers[i].visible,
        img: jen.infLayers[i].img,
        lyrType: jen.infLayers[i].lyrType
      });
    }
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Normally, you do that by making the function a method of said object. Which you appear to be doing. I'm afraid there's not enough code provided for us to understand the problem.

Comment: This totally depends on what `doFirst` actually does.

Comment: Why not just call `availableSecond` as a callback?

Comment: @JeffShaver why use callbacks when you can use `deferred`?

Comment: Thanks for the `addLayer` code. But how is that invoked by `doFirst`, and what are `jen.inflayers` and `setLayer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. Deferred certainly can help. Decoupling your functions is another way, but here is a deferred solution:

```
foo = (function () {
    var first_deferred = $.Deferred();
    return {
        doFirst: function () {
            console.log("first");
            first_deferred.resolve();
        },
        availableSecond: function () {
            first_deferred.done(function () {
                console.log("second");
            });
        }
    };
}());
```

Now if you call:

```
foo.availableSecond(); // prints nothing
foo.doFirst(); /// prints first second
```

Other order:

```
foo.doFirst(); /// prints first
foo.availableSecond(); // prints second
```

Comment: That only "works" if you call `availableSecond()` before `doFirst()`

Comment: Nope, it works in both orders, that's how deferred works. `second` will never come before `first`.

Comment: It didn't work. That is the issue. It doesn't print out `second` unless you call `availableSecond` first. I copied and pasted your code, so it wasn't a mistype on my end.

Comment: @JeffShaver: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/pmNtS/) [flawlessly](http://jsfiddle.net/pmNtS/1/) both orders. Notice that a single deferred can only be resolved once, you might have made the mistake of copying both calls into the same fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> … needs the array of objects created in `foo.doFirst();` …

Then that might be what the `doFirst` method should return, instead of hiding it somewhere on/in the `foo` object. If the array is created asynchronously, you should return a promise for it (show us the code you've tried for the deferreds to get help with it).

> is it possible to make a function available after an object has been instantiated?

Sure, just make that function a method of the instantiated object.